# How to run cmd's goto command (or other) with bat-file from vbscript?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, vbscript

I would like to run `file.bat` with parameters through a `vbscript` like this:

```vb
Function RunMove()
wshShell.Run("file.bat goto X")
End Function
```

Comment: You'll need to get the stdin inside of the batch file. Create a function for it in the batch-file itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a function inside your `batch-file` as a macro to do something with parameters from `stdin`, if received. You posted no batch code, so here is a dummy example:

```
@echo off
If "%3" == "" if not "%2" == "" if /i "%1" == "goto" %*
goto :eof
:X
echo You requested 'goto :loop'
```

So in this case in the example you gave, if you run `file.bat goto X` it will reach use the macro to reach that label.

Comment: Much simpler: `if "%1" neq "" %*` This works with _any_ Batch-file command...

Comment: What if `%2` is empty, @Aacini? `goto` on its own will cause a syntax error.